# Loop to every each row of php array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

Hello I have 2 sets of code here and here it is

`Ajax`

```
/* Loop and Get Data from database to create a table */
$(document).ready(function () { 
   $('#btngenerate').click(function(e){
       var d1 = $('#startdate').val();
       var d2 = $('#enddate').val();
         $.ajax({
            url: 'queries/qryTITO.php',
            type: "POST",
            datatype: 'json',
            data: ({startdate: d1,enddate: d2}),
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });  
   });
});
```

and here is the `PHP`

```
<?php
    require 'conn.php';
    $startdate = $_POST['startdate'];
    $enddate   = $_POST['enddate'];
    $sql       = "SELECT vdate FROM tablename WHERE date(vdate) between date('" . $startdate . "') and date('" . $enddate . "')";
    $result    = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $row       = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    $jsonData = array();
    while ($array = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        $jsonData[] =  $array;
    }
    echo json_encode($jsonData);
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

here is my question. I am trying to return the value back to the jquery so I can create a HTML Table. actually it is working and this is the output

[image]

My question here is how can I make an HTML table for that data?

Here is the error i get

[image]

Comment: You should know that you have a serious SQL injection vulnerability.  SQL injection is one of the most dangerous web application vulnerabilities.  Prepared statements are a good start on securing yourself: give them a google!

Comment: noted sir actually thats my target after achieving my problem here.

Comment: you can loop it inside the success and then append it to a table..

Comment: the append table is ok for me but im having the problem in the loop part

Comment: You should set content type `application/json` at PHP end and  T should be capital in ajax parameter `dataType`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
   $('#btngenerate').click(function(e){
       var d1 = $('#startdate').val();
       var d2 = $('#enddate').val();
         $.ajax({
            url: 'queries/qryTITO.php',
            type: "POST",
            datatype: 'json',
            data: ({startdate: d1,enddate: d2}),
            success: function(data){
                    $.each(data,function(){
                        $('tr').append("<td>"+this+"</td>")
                    });
            }
        });  
   });
});
```

here is a [**Sample Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mWvjM/36/)..

Comment: Hi Sir thnx for the effort however but it gives me an error and sir can you give me a more detail sample because it is more than 1 column that i will display.

Comment: Sir Please bere with me I am trying to display 5 columns what should i do

Comment: here is the error `Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length'`

Comment: for example my select command has 4 columns and I will display that in table

Comment: Sir i pasted the error in my post. I just copy and paste the code youve given sir

Comment: sir if my codes does not fit for your needs. I will be glad if you want to edit it also

Comment: try `$.each(JSON.parse(data),function(){` if it will still get an error..

Comment: we have the same idea sir haha. I also make it like that cause `in` is a object last one sir. how about if it is more 2 columns? by the way your code worked now

Comment: is the number of columns fix? tapos kung pinoy ka pwede tagalog.. nakakapagod mag english..

Comment: sige sir tagalog nalang hahah. sir i fix ko sya ng 6 columns

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155731/discussion-between-shadow-fiend-and-paul-pagente). Sa chat para mabilis

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  $('#btngenerate').click(function(e){
    var d1 = $('#startdate').val();
    var d2 = $('#enddate').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'queries/qryTITO.php',
      type: "POST",
      datatype: 'json',
      data: ({startdate: d1,enddate: d2}),
      success: function(data){
        $(data).each(function(i,res){
          $('table').append("<tr><td>"+res.vdate+"</td></tr>");
        });
      }
    });  
  });
});
```

Comment: oops..semicolon missing out there..fixed