# How to pass value from HTML to PHP and display it using Include

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have 3 HTML Elements

```
<input id = "startdate" name = "startdate" type="text" class="datepicker form-control" placeholder="Start Date...">
<input id = "enddate" name = "enddate" type="text" class="datepicker form-control" placeholder="End Date...">
<button class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary waves-effect" id="btngenerate" name="btngenerate">Generate FSP Report</button>
```

and a qry_vsr.php

```
<?php
require 'conn.php';
$startdate = $_POST['startdate'];
$enddate = $_POST['enddate'];


$sql = 'My Query Here with the parameter'
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while ($array = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo 'Create Table';
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Now I call this php file in include in a table

```
<table id="dtable" name="dtable" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover js-basic-example dataTable">
    <thead id="thead" name="thead">
        <tr>
            <th>Table Headers Here</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id = "tblreport">
        <?php include('../../php/pages/sfa/qry_vsr.php') ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now here is my question.

How can I pass those element value in the `qry_vsr.php` without refreshing or going to blank page and populate data in this php include inside the table?

here is the ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btngenerate').click(function (e) {
        var d1 = $('#startdate').val();
        var d2 = $('#enddate').val();
        var fspcode = $('#fspcode').find(":selected").text();
        var count = 0;
        var i;
        var x;


        if (d1 == "" || d2 == "" || fspcode == "Nothing Selected") {
            sfaMsgbox('Please provide proper date range and select FSP.');
        } else if (d2 < d1) {
            sfaMsgbox('Improper date range.');
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                url: '../../php/pages/sfa/qry_vsr.php',
                type: "POST",
                datatype: 'json',
                data: ({
                    startdate: d1,
                    enddate: d2,
                    fsp: fspcode
                })
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Try `ajax` it will help you.

Comment: hi sir @ShadowFiend please see the edited post

Comment: @paulpagente i didn;t see any changes in your post..

Comment: what a hint? proudly pinoy hahaha  here is the link of your help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46518784/loop-to-every-each-row-of-php-array/46518989?noredirect=1#comment79992353_46518989

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing PHP variable to Jquery without refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945027/passing-php-variable-to-jquery-without-refresh)

Comment: hahaha.. yeah I remember now..  have you tried `success:function(data){append data here}`?

Comment: @paulpagente try to read the link suggestion of Sand..

Comment: already tried that but my target here is too create a htmlelement the `<tr><td>` using php because im trying to use a class

Comment: @paulpagente duon mo e create ang table sa qry_vsr.php, e echo mo lang yung table.. tapos e append sa succes. yun tapos..

Comment: yung nga itetest ko sir. try ko sir

Comment: not working sir :(

Comment: and also sir i have an error of undefined index

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156327/discussion-between-paul-pagente-and-shadow-fiend).

Answer (score 0):

on ajax success

```
$('#tblreport').load('../../php/pages/sfa/qry_vsr.php');
```

Comment: undefined index on my variables sir

Comment: Your data also doesnt need ()'s. use { only.

Comment: Yes sir. I try to put sample parameter and it works right

Comment: after removing the ()'s from data do you still get it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156328/discussion-between-guney-saramali-and-paul-pagente).